# Coefficients of a polynomial representation of factorials

Tags: factorial

I'm trying to figure out the coefficients of
 $${(k+d)!}/{(k-n)!}$$ 
when expressed as a polynomial.  Any ideas?

Comment: Polynomial... In variable $k$?

Answer (score 1):

I presume this is supposed to be a polynomial in $k$.
$$\dfrac{(k+d)!}{(k-n)!} = \prod_{j=-n+1}^d (k+j)$$
The coefficient of $k^i$ is the sum of the products of all subsets of
$\{-n+1, \ldots, d\}$ having cardinality
$d+n-i$.